# npm run dev doesn't work

Tags: laravel, npm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5M86.jpg)I run `npm run dev` but I get this:

> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok 
>  1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe',
>  1 verbose cli   'C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
>  1 verbose cli
>   'run',
>  1 verbose cli   'dev' ]
>  2 info using npm@5.5.1
>  3
>   info using node@v8.9.1
>  4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev',
>   'postdev' ]
>  5 info lifecycle @~predev: @
>  6 info lifecycle
>   @~dev: @
>  7 verbose lifecycle @~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle
>   true
>  8 verbose lifecycle @~dev: PATH: C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;c:\xampp\htdocs\laravelapp\node_modules.bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;E:\Java\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\;C:\Program
>   Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin;L:\Microsof3t VS
>   Code\bin;C:\Users\SuperServer\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\SuperServer\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Xampp\php;C:\Users\SuperServer\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;E:\nodeJs\npm;E:\NodeJS\node_modules\npm;C:\Users\SuperServer\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin;
>  9 verbose lifecycle @~dev:
>   CWD: c:\xampp\htdocs\laravelapp
>  10 silly lifecycle @~dev: Args: [
>   '/d /s /c', 'npm run development' ]
>  11 info lifecycle @~dev:
>   Failed to exec dev script
>  12 silly lifecycle @~dev: Returned:
>   code: -4058  signal: null
>  13 info lifecycle @~dev: Failed to exec
>   dev script
>  14 verbose stack Error: @ dev: `npm run
>   development`
>  14 verbose stack spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;
>   E:\Java\bin ENOENT
>  14 verbose stack     at _errnoException
>   (util.js:1024:11)
>  14 verbose stack     at
>   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
>  14 verbose stack     at
>   onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
>  14 verbose stack
>   at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
>   14 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
>  15 verbose pkgid @
>  16
>   verbose cwd c:\xampp\htdocs\laravelapp
>  17 verbose Windows_NT
>   6.1.7601
>  18 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run"
>   "dev"
>  19 verbose node v8.9.1
>  20 verbose npm  v5.5.1
>  21
>   error file C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe; E:\Java\bin
>  22 error path
>   C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe; E:\Java\bin
>  23 error code
>   ELIFECYCLE
>  24 error errno ENOENT
>  25 error syscall spawn
>   C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe; E:\Java\bin
>  26 error @ dev: `npm run
>   development`
>  26 error spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;
>   E:\Java\bin ENOENT
>  27 error Failed at the @ dev script.
>  27
>   error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
>   additional logging output above.
>  28 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Did you add you run script in package.json file

Comment: Looks like your npm version is outdated, update it and try it again.

Comment: I've added a screen shot of the terminal where I ran the "npm run dev"
to show the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your "dev" task errors because it tries to spawn a new java process with the java binary located at `E:\Java\bin` but this binary doesn't exist (ENOENT). Can you add an excerpt of the "package.json" file with definition of your "dev" script?

Answer (score -1):

This is a pretty common error. Especially if you are running your npm command from an integrated terminal.

Try running your npm commands from a separate PowerShell or CMD command prompt terminal and you would be just fine.

I hope this helps someone out there.